# Flatbutton(Input handler) doesn't seems to work

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I try to use file uploader from materila-ui, but it doesn't seems to work and get the input from selecting file. 
 Anyone have any advice how to get the input from file selector and handle it.

```
<FlatButton
            icon={<i className="material-icons">attachment</i>}
            onclick={e => this._handleChange(e)}
            onchange={e => this._openFileDialog(e)}
          >
            <input type="file" style={styles.uploadInput} />
          </FlatButton>
```

http://material-ui.com/#/components/flat-button

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining onChange event on `FlatButton`, define it on `input` element, Write it like this:

```
<FlatButton
      icon={<i className="material-icons">attachment</i>}
      onClick={e => this._handleChange(e)}
>
    <input type="file" onChange={this._handleFileUpload.bind(this)}/>
</FlatButton>
```

Then in `onChange` method by using `e.target.files`, you can access the selected file:

```
_handleFileUpload(e){
   console.log(e.target.files);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the button in a label, and point it at the file input which can be hidden.

```
<label htmlFor={id}>
  <FlatButton />
</label>
<input type="file" id={id} onChange={(e) => {
  const file = e.target.files[0];
  // do stuff
}}
```

Generate a random id in constructor to use here.